# Gitlab Maven Repository upload jar error when try do download it from pipeline

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I made a maven project saved into a gitlab project (PROJECT_A). With pipeline I publish this project into a gitlab maven repository. Here the settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Job-Token</name>
                        <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And this is the reference to the repository into the pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

The PROJECT_A jar is used as maven dependency into another project (PROJECT_B). Into the pom.xml of this latter project I had declared the repository reference where the jar is published, here the code

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_A_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

If I run the project in local everything it's ok, the dependency is downloaded and I'm able to use it into PROJECT_B. But when I push some change into gitlab, when the pipeline run (into a gitlab shared runner) the command `mvn clean install -DskipTests` I receive the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cost-center: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.phatedeveloper:cost-center:jar:0.0.1: Could not find artifact com.phatedeveloper:pbm-dto-library:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/20364942/packages/maven) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to set the repository based on Group ID to be shared between projects.

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <url>https://code.siemens.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```